# Can't Ping Instances or SSH into Instances from Host

Tags: ssh, ping, devstack

I have installed Devstack successfully in Ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox VM.

```
enp0s3 :10.6.208.111 
lo: 127.0.0.1 
virbr0: 192.168.122.1
```

I have both default public and private network in my topology network with a router.

I am not able to ping between my host and the instance created (`IP:192.168.101.3` and `floating IPs: 172.24.4.15`). `Host IP: 10.6.208.111`

Current settings:

```
Public Network (public 172.24.4.0/27) 
Private Network (private 192.168.101.0/24)
```

I also created a floating IP with the IP address `172.24.4.15`

I created a router with 2 interfaces: one connects to the public and one connects to the private. I created the VM's in the private network.

How can I SSH to the instance created and ping it from my host IP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I did for ocata version devstack installation with the single NIC, May be this will help.

1. Install the openstack with devstack ocata version
2. Delete the existing/default networks 
   2.1 Deletet all the router interfaces and then the router
   2.2 Deletet all the networks
3. Create the networks public and private
4. Add the router and its interfaces to public and private network
5. Add the TCP and ICMP to the security Group.(Networktopology> security group> manage rules> add)
6. Configure the Bridge in command prompt

Note:
Make sure the details like bridge, interface, network ip to be changes as per your need.

- Public netwrok : 10.0.15.0
- private network: 192.168.11.0
- external bridge: br-ex
- interface      : enp0s8
- Ubuntu ip      : 10.0.15.20

## 3 Create the network private

```
    project:admin
    project >
    network topology >
    create a network > 
    network name : private-net
    enable admin state: yes
    shared :no
    create subnet:yes
    next >


    subnet name : private-net-subnet
    Network Address Source : enter network address manually
    Network Address : 192.168.11.0/24
    IP Version : IPV4
    Gateway IP : 192.168.11.1
    Disable Gateway : No
    next >

    Enable DHCP : yes
    Allocation Pools : 192.168.11.120,192.168.11.140
    DNS Name Servers : 8.8.8.8
    Host Routes :
```

## 3 Create the network public

```
    admin >
    networks > 
    Create Network >
    Name : public-net
    Project : demo
    Provider Network Type : Flat
    Physical Network : public
    Enable Admin State : yes
    Shared : yes
    External Network : yes

    public-net > 
    Create subnet >
    Subnet Name : public-net-subnet
    Network Address Source : enter network address manually
    Network Address : 10.0.15.0/24
    IP Version : IPV4
    Gateway IP : 10.0.15.1
    Disable Gateway : No
    next >

    Enable DHCP : yes
    Allocation Pools : 10.0.15.120,10.0.15.140
    DNS Name Servers : 10.0.9.10
    Host Routes :
```

## 4 Adding the router and its interfaces to public and private network

```
    admin >
    networks > 
    Routers >
    Create Router >
    Router Name : router 1
    Enable Admin State : yes
    External Network : public-net
    create Router > 

    project >
    networks > 
    Routers >
    router 1 >
    interfaces >
    add interface >
    subnet : private-net
    ip address : 
    submit >
```

## 6 Configure the Bridge in command prompt (ubuntu openstack host)

```
sudo ifconfig br-ex promisc up
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex enp0s8 & sudo ifconfig br-ex 10.0.15.20 netmask 255.255.255.0
systemctl restart networking.service
```